# Iteration SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have very difficult scenario in my Oracle DB. I have a table setup as following:

```
ID              File_route_group   CollectID      DeliveryID      Sequence
----------      ------------       ---------      ------------    --------
11483              12                 123            411             1
12174              12                 411            523             2
12465              12                 523            611             3
12165              46                 215            662             1
52462              12                 266            394             4
12199              46                 662            718             2
61244              12                 394            980             5
```

Each line represents a "route" a certain file has taken and the following row (next sequence) should always have the same CollectID as the previous sequences DeliveryID.

In this example row ID 52462 is wrong. It should have collectID 611 (as row with sequence 3 have that as its deliveryID).

Is there a way to create a query that would have returned this row (with id 52462)? Like following:

```
ID              File_route_group   CollectID      DeliveryID      Sequence
----------      ------------       ---------      ------------    --------
52462              12                 266            394             4
```

Comment: You should post the data and the desired result that you want.

Comment: What is the table structure by the way?

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH cte AS
( SELECT ID,
         File_route_group,
         CollectID, 
         DeliveryID,
         Sequence,
         LAG(DeliveryID, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY File_route_group 
                                     ORDER BY Sequence)
             Previous_DeliveryID
  FROM Routes
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE ( CollectID <> Previous_DeliveryID
     OR CollectID IS NULL
     OR Previous_DeliveryID IS NULL
      )
  AND Sequence > 1 ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c49a/17)**

Comment: I didn't know about SQL-Fiddle. Nice one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table with itself to represent the relation between the 'current' and the 'previous' entry:

```
SELECT * FROM route current_route
JOIN route last_route 
  ON current_route.Sequence = last_route.Sequence + 1
  AND current_route.File_route_grp = last_route.File_route_grp
WHERE current_route.CollectID <> last_route.DeliveryID
```

Note that while the usage of LAG() proposed in the other answers is the more elegant and possibly more performant way of doing this in Oracle, this solution is more portable and also works, e.g. with MySQL and other DBMS.

Comment: You need another join-condition: `and current_route.File_route_grp = last_route.File_route_grp` or you will compare the IDs of different routing_groups with each other

Comment: Thank you for your remark. The question has been updated after I had given my answer. I have now added the additional criteria and also added a remark about portability.

Answer (score 0):

In a derived table use the [`LAG`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php) function to get the `PreviousDeliveryID` then filter that where the `CollectionId` does not equal `PreviousDeliveryID`

```
SELECT ID, Customer_id, CollectID, DeliveryID, Sequence
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Customer_id, CollectID, DeliveryID, Sequence, LAG(DeliveryID, 1) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS PrevDeliveryID
    FROM Routes
) AS t
WHERE t.CollectionID <> t.PrevDeliveryID
```